# How can I determine if clients are connected to my socket?

Tags: c, sockets, unix, posix

I have code that calls a library (gstreamer, in this case) that opens a TCP server socket. I have the port number but I do not have access to the file descriptor.

I'd like to detect from my app whether there are clients currently connected to this port. Ideally, I'd like a cross-platform approach (Linux + Mac, bonus points for *BSD).

I know that `netstat` could help me do that, but I'd like a programmatic technique.

Comment: On Linux you can read from `/proc/net/tcp`.

Comment: why not get the source code for `netstat` and see how it's done?

Comment: If you can't do it via the library itself, it seems like a bad idea. I believe gstreamer runs its own thread, so by the time you check and get the response (0 connections), you may actually have a new connection.

Comment: Seems like `popen("netstat")` is the only way to accomplish this task in less or more cross-platform manner.

Comment: @viraptor I'm willing to live with that race condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library code runs in your process's address space.  The file descriptor(s) it uses are just `int` values that you can use `getsockopt()` on to find TCP/IP sockets, then `getpeername()` on those sockets to find connected ones.  Per the POSIX documentation [for getsockopt()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getsockopt.html) and [`getpeername()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getpeername.html):

```
#include <sys/socket.h>

// probably better to use getrlimit() here...
#define MAX_FD 1024

int tcp_socket_fds[ MAX_FD ];
struct sockaddr_in peers[ MAX_FD ];

for ( int fd = 0; fd < MAX_FD; fd++ )
{
    int type;
    int len = sizeof( type );

    int rc = getsockopt( fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_TYPE, &type, &len );    
    if ( ( 0 == rc ) && ( SOCK_STREAM == type ) )
    {
        tcp_socket_fds[ fd ] = 1;

        socklen_t socket_len = sizeof( peers[ fd ] );
        rc = getpeername( fd, &( peers[ fd ] ), &socket_len );

        // zero out the peer if getpeername() failed
        if ( 0 != rc )
        {
            memset( &( peers[ fd ], 0, sizeof( peers[ fd ] ) );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        tcp_socket_fds[ fd ] = 0;
    }
}
```

That will find all connected TCP sockets your process has open at the time of the check, and it should be fairly portable.

Comment: Mmmh... I can't quite parse then manpage: will `getpeername` tell me if a client is connected to my socket?

Comment: @Yoric The entire purpose of `getpeername()` is to tell you *who* is connected to the other end of the socket.  In doing so, it tells you *if* it's connected.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Serhio. If you open /proc//net/tcp and read it, you'll see:

```
 sl  local_address rem_address   st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt   uid  timeout inode                                                     
   0: 0100007F:0CEA 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000   116        0 14581 1 ffff880406690000 100 0 0 10 0                     
   1: 00000000:008B 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 15646 1 ffff880404aa8700 100 0 0 10 0                     
   2: 0100007F:13AD 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000  1000        0 16859998 1 ffff880406692a00 100 0 0 10 0                  
   3: 0100007F:F76E 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000  1000        0 31381008 1 ffff8800d7926200 100 0 0 10 0  
...
```

From the proc [manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html):

> ```
>  /proc/net/tcp
>               Holds a dump of the TCP socket table.  Much of the information
>               is not of use apart from debugging.  The "sl" value is the
>               kernel hash slot for the socket, the "local_address" is the
>               local address and port number pair.  The "rem_address" is the
>               remote address and port number pair (if connected).  "St" is
>               the internal status of the socket.  The "tx_queue" and
>               "rx_queue" are the outgoing and incoming data queue in terms
>               of kernel memory usage.  The "tr", "tm->when", and "rexmits"
>               fields hold internal information of the kernel socket state
>               and are useful only for debugging.  The "uid" field holds the
>               effective UID of the creator of the socket.
> ```

So, parse out these lines (skip first line then sscanf) and extract the port numbers from the local_address field to find the port you are interested in. Look at the st field to find sockets in the connected state. If you find anything in the connected state, return true.